# Android Robo test cannot find element

Tags: android, firebase, android-testing, firebase-test-lab

I want to use Robo test from google firebase for my application. 
My application needs login process.
I want to use resource and value mapping system.

I filled in the form like this

[image]

However, test report says that there are no such resource names

[image]

Resource name was copied from android UI Automator Viewer like below

[image]

Did I do something wrong?
Is it related to security of my company's application?

Answer (score 1):

The Robo UX Test docs(https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/robo-ux-test) say that it is only compatible with the Android UI framework.  I don't know what you're using, but we are building in Xamarin.Forms and I haven't been able to get Robo to accept our resource field names and text entry.

Robo test currently has the following known limitations:

UI framework support. Robo test is only compatible with apps that use UI elements from the Android UI framework (including View and ViewGroup objects, but excluding WebView objects). If you use Robo test to exercise apps that use other UI frameworks, including apps that use the Unity game engine, the test may exit without exploring beyond the first screen.